# UK Counties list not complete - can this be amended by user or does it need to be amended in the core program?

Tags: contacts

The drop down list of UK Counties does not seem to include Middlesex.  Can the drop down list be amended?

Comment: Welcome to SE! I suspect the answer to your question is no, but what is your purpose of using county? In addresses the Post Office no longer uses counties (just post town and postcode). There are also administrative counties, but Middlesex ceased to be one of those ages ago. I think the information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counties_of_the_United_Kingdom is reasonably correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can amend this list directly in the DB if you want to. You can find the relevant data in the civicrm_state_province table. To see the values for the UK use:

```
select *  from civicrm_state_province csp where country_id = 1226
```